# Найти часть кода HTML на странице

Tags: javascript

Извиняюсь за тупой вопрос, но мне нужно найти кусок кода и заменить его на странице, но проблема в том, что этот кусок кода находится внизу списка, а список постоянно подгружается со страницы. Пытаюсь сделать js скрипт в tampermonkey, пробовал через innerhtml.replace,, но он выполняется 1 раз и ничего не меняет, т.к нужного куска еще нет на странице, пробовал через match, но всегда true, даже когда кода нет, как можно сделать постоянный поиск нужной части кода и только потом замена его?

Пытался использовать innerhtml.replace, но он срабатывает сразу, так же отсрочка по времени не вариант использовать, страницу могут крутить не с одной скоростью

Comment: innerHTML лучше в процессе подгрузки не реплейсить. Если хотите что-то поменять - лучше найтиде элемент внутри структуры и меняйте конкретно его. При замене innerHTML вы заставляете бразуер перекомпилировать страницу. Что будет с страницой если она ещё грузится и заменили innerHTML - не знаю... наверно каша.

Comment: Для поиска элемента ищите хотя бы через document.all (я так делаю), но лучше через document.body или document.getElementById и потом через firstChild и nextSibling делать поиск-сканирование, можно рекурсивно. Так же есть JQuery по JQuery неподскажу. Для поиска пользуюсь tagName и innerHTML. Для замены текста менять innerHTML и желательно что бы внутри небыло тегов ломающих структуру документа. Для замены атрибутов либо attribs либо outerHTML

Comment: `страницу могут крутить не с одной скоростью` дык... `<body onscroll='console.log("к скролу код и привяжи")'>` а еще лучше, дополни функцию подзагрузки контента